# How to encode self-delimited opus in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder, opus

I can record opus using AVAudioRecorder as following:

```
let opusRecordingSettings = [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatOpus,
                             AVSampleRateKey: 16000.0,
                             AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1] as [String: Any]
                             
do {
    try audioRecordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
    try audioRecordingSession.setActive(true)

    audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileUrl(), settings: opusRecordingSettings)
    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
}
catch _ { }

// ... ... ...
```

Now I need to encode opus as following:

```
| header | encoded opus data | header | encoded opus data | ... | ... |
```

Each header indicates the size of opus data (in bytes)

I am guessing (correct me if I am wrong):

- AVAudioRecorder puts opus packets continuously side by side (since by
  default opus packets are non-delimited) in a `.opus` file after
  recording is finished
- default frame duration is 20 ms and therefore `frameSize = 20 * 16 = 320` ( since I am using 16 kHz sample rate)
- each packet contains exactly one frame and therefore `packetSize == frameSize`

I understand that if I can somehow loop over the opus packets, then I can calculate size of each packet and append it as header (`dataChunk = header + encodedOpusData`)

I got the concept of self delimited opus from: [ietf.org/Self-Delimiting-Framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6716#appendix-B) but don't know the following:

- **how to create delimited opus audio file** (*delimited by header where header indicates size of opus data in bytes*)
- **how and when to append header** (*while recording or after recording is completed?*)

Comment: What does AVAudioRecorder output? AVAudioRecorder cannot give you an uninterrupted sequence of opus packets without any added headers as the stream would be useless. So I suppose there's some container involved, maybe ogg?

Comment: @Damiano no container is involved. encoded opus will be send to server. About playback, I am decoding to PCM and adding WAV header to play (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597315/playing-custom-opus-audio-file-in-ios). Decoding is OK, I just need to figure out how to encode as `|header|data|header|data|...|...|`. I am trying AudioEngine now but could not make it work yet. Using a mixtureNode and tapping on it but getting silence only :(, probably messing up something (i.e. AVAudioFormat or session or something, I don't know)

Comment: There something missin from the equation because even if you compress opus cbr, the frame size can vary by some bytes. So, if AVAudioRecorder does't have a callback for every frame encoded it must put some framing or use some container.

Comment: @Damiano, Frame: 20ms, SampleRate: 16kHz, 1 channel = 320 bytes and I am splitting Linear PCM into 640 bytes chunk and encoding that chunk using libopus (2 frames), encoding is working (I tested). I recorded Linear PCM using AVAudioRecorder and saved as `foo.raw` then loaded that `foo.raw` using `Data(contentsOf: ... )` then splitting into 640 bytes chunk and feeding to libopus `opus_encode(... ... ...)`

Comment: Then you should use the callback from opus_encode to feed your output stream with a word/half word with frame length and then the packet itself and so on. Keep in mind that that way, without an container, no common player/lib will ever play it. You need a container/streaming protocol on top to made it available to other apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to encode self-delimited opus using `AVAudioRecorder` and `AVAssetReader` (complete solution: [hovermind.com/ios/libopus-kit](https://hovermind.com/ios/libopus-kit))

> FYI, this is probably not elegant solution but other methods i.e.
> tapping on InputNode of AudioEngine or using AudioQueue did not work
> for me. If anyone finds elegant solution, can suggest an edit of this
> answer

Here is the summery (code below):

- record **Linear PCM** using `AVAudioRecorder` and save recorded audio file
  i.e. `temp.wav`
- read recorded audio file using `AVAssetReader` and extract PCM (don't load audio file using `Data(contentsOf: ...)`, there is metadata/header in the audio file that would cause some noise)
- split PCM data into `x` byte chunks and loop over it (in my case `x = 640`)
- encode `x` byte PCM chunk to opus using [OpusKit](http://cocoapods.org/pods/OpusKit) pod
- calculate size of encoded opus and append as header

Code (*Swift 5, iOS 13, Xcode 11.3*)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import MessageKit
import AVFoundation
import OpusKit
import os

class BasicChatViewController: ChatViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        Logger.logIt("Initilizing opus lib kit")
        OpusKit.shared.initialize(sampleRate: Opus.SAMPLE_RATE_DEFAULT,
                                  numberOfChannels: Opus.CHANNEL_COUNT_DEFAULT,
                                  packetSize: Opus.OPUS_ENCODER_BUFFER_SIZE,
                                  encodeBlockSize: Opus.FRAME_SIZE_DEFAULT)
                                  
        // configure record button here
    }
    
    //
    // MARK - recording
    //
    var isRecording = false
    var avAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    
    @objc
    func onTapRecordButton(sender: UIButton){
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        toggleRecording()
    }
    
    private func toggleRecording(){
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        Logger.logIt("isRecording: \(isRecording)")
        
        if isRecording {
            
            isRecording = false
            
            stopRecording()
            
        } else {
            
            isRecording = true
            
            checkPermissionAndStartRecording()
        }
    }
    //
    // END - recording
    //
}
//
// Audio recording related extensions
//
extension BasicChatViewController: AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    
    private func checkPermissionAndStartRecording() {
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        AudioUtil.checkRecordingPermission() { isPermissionGranted in
            
            Logger.logIt("isPermissionGranted: \(isPermissionGranted)")
            
            if isPermissionGranted {
                self.recordUsingAVAudioRecorder()
            } else {
                Logger.logIt("don't have permission to record")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setupRecorder() {
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        let tempAudioFileUrl = AudioUtil.TEMP_WAV_FILE
        Logger.logIt("tempAudioFileUrl: \(tempAudioFileUrl)")
        
        let linearPcmRecordingSettings = LinearPCMRecording.LINEAR_PCM_RECODING_SETTINGS_DEFAULT
        Logger.logIt("RecordingSettings: \(linearPcmRecordingSettings)")
        
        do {
            
            startRecordingSession()
            
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: tempAudioFileUrl, settings: linearPcmRecordingSettings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            //audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
            audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        }
        catch {
            Logger.logIt("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    private func startRecording() {
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        if audioRecorder == nil {
            setupRecorder()
        }
        
        audioRecorder.record()
    }
    
    private func stopRecording() {
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        guard audioRecorder != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        audioRecorder.stop()
    }
    
    private func deleteTempAudioFile(){
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        guard audioRecorder != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        if audioRecorder.isRecording {
            return
        }
        
        // delete temporary audio file
        let recordingDeleted = audioRecorder.deleteRecording()
        if recordingDeleted {
            Logger.logIt("temp (recorded) audio file deleted")
        } else {
            Logger.logIt("failed to delete temp (recorded) audio file")
        }
    }
    
    private func startRecordingSession(){
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.record, mode: .spokenAudio)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            Logger.logIt("Failed to deactivate recording session")
        }
    }
    
    private func stopRecordingSession(){
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
        } catch {
            Logger.logIt("Failed to deactivate recording session")
        }
    }
    
    private func recordUsingAVAudioRecorder(){
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        setupRecorder()
        
        startRecording()
    }
    
    private func encodeRecordedAudio(){
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        let pcmData = AudioUtil.extractPcmOnly(from: AudioUtil.TEMP_WAV_FILE)
        
        if pcmData.count > 1 {
            
            Logger.logIt("encoding pcm to self-delimited opus")
            
            let encodedOpusData = AudioUtil.encodeToSelfDelimitedOpus(pcmData: pcmData, splitSize: PCM.SPLIT_CHUNK_SIZE_DEFAULT)
            Logger.logIt("encoded opus: \(encodedOpusData)")
            
            
            Logger.logIt("save encoded opus")
            AudioUtil.saveAudio(to: AudioUtil.ENCODED_OPUS_FILE, audioData: encodedOpusData)
            
        } else {
            Logger.logIt("no data to encode")
        }

        deleteTempAudioFile()
        stopRecordingSession()
    }
    
    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        let finishedSuccessFully = flag
        
        if finishedSuccessFully {
            
            Logger.logIt("finished recording successfully")
            
            encodeRecordedAudio()
            
        } else {
            Logger.logIt("recording failed - audio encoding error")
        }
    }
}
```

**AudioUtil**

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import OpusKit


//
// Opus audio info.
//
public class OpusAudioInfo {
    
    public static let `default` = OpusAudioInfo()
    
    var channels: opus_int32
    var headerSize: Int // bytes
    var packetSize: opus_int32
    var sampleRate: opus_int32 {
        didSet {
            packetSize = Int32(Opus.FRAME_DURATION_DEFAULT) * (sampleRate / 1000)
        }
    }
    
    public init(sampleRate: opus_int32 = Opus.SAMPLE_RATE_16_KHZ,
                channels: opus_int32 = Opus.CHANNEL_COUNT_DEFAULT,
                headerSize: Int = 1) {
        self.sampleRate = sampleRate
        self.packetSize =  Int32(Opus.FRAME_DURATION_DEFAULT) * (sampleRate / 1000)
        self.channels = channels
        self.headerSize = headerSize
    }
}

//
// RAW PCM info.
//
public class PCMInfo {
    
    public static let `default` = PCMInfo()
    
    var sampleRate:Int32
    var channels:Int16
    var bitDepth:Int16
    
    public init(sampleRate:Int32 = PCM.SAMPLE_RATE_16_KHZ,
                channels:Int16 = Int16(PCM.MONO),
                bitDepth:Int16 = Int16(PCM.BIT_DEPTH_DEFAULT)) {
        self.sampleRate = sampleRate
        self.channels = channels
        self.bitDepth = bitDepth
    }
}

//
// Utility class for audio related operations
//
public class AudioUtil {
    
    private init(){}

    
    
    //
    // Default audio files url in document directory
    //
    public static let RAW_PCM_FILE = FileUtil.createFileUrl(for: "pcm.raw", in: FileUtil.DOCUMENTS_DIR)
    public static let TEMP_WAV_FILE = FileUtil.createFileUrl(for: "wav.wav", in: FileUtil.DOCUMENTS_DIR)
    public static let ENCODED_OPUS_FILE = FileUtil.createFileUrl(for: "encoded_opus_ios.opus", in: FileUtil.DOCUMENTS_DIR)
    public static let DECODED_WAV_WITH_HEADER_FILE = FileUtil.createFileUrl(for: "decoded_wav_with_header.wav", in: FileUtil.DOCUMENTS_DIR)

/**
 Creates fake wav header to play Linear PCM
 
 AVAudioPlayer by default can not play Linear PCM, therefore we need to create a fake wav header
 
 - parameter sampleRate: samples per second
 - parameter channelCount: number of channels
 - parameter bitDepth: bits per sample
 - parameter pcmDataSizeInBytes: PCM data size in bytes
 
 - returns : Data - wav header data
 */
public static func createWavHeader(sampleRate: Int32, channelCount: Int16, bitDepth: Int16, pcmDataSizeInBytes dataSize: Int32) -> Data {
    
    /*
     
     WAV header details: http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html
     
     Positions    Sample Value    Description
     1 - 4    "RIFF"    Marks the file as a riff file. Characters are each 1 byte long.
     5 - 8    File size (integer)    Size of the overall file - 8 bytes, in bytes (32-bit integer). Typically, you'd fill this in after creation.
     9 -12    "WAVE"    File Type Header. For our purposes, it always equals "WAVE".
     13-16    "fmt "    Format chunk marker. Includes trailing null
     17-20    16    Length of format data as listed above
     21-22    1    Type of format (1 is PCM) - 2 byte integer
     23-24    2    Number of Channels - 2 byte integer
     25-28    44100    Sample Rate - 32 byte integer. Common values are 44100 (CD), 48000 (DAT). Sample Rate = Number of Samples per second, or Hertz.
     29-32    176400    (Sample Rate * BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8.
     33-34    4    (BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8.1 - 8 bit mono2 - 8 bit stereo/16 bit mono4 - 16 bit stereo
     35-36    16    Bits per sample
     37-40    "data"    "data" chunk header. Marks the beginning of the data section.
     41-44    File size (data)    Size of the data section.
     Sample values are given above for a 16-bit stereo source.
     
     
     
     An example in swift :
     
     let WAV_HEADER: [Any] = [
     "R","I","F","F",
     0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,  // file size
     "W","A","V","E",
     "f","m","t"," ",      // Chunk ID
     0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,  // Chunk Size - length of format above
     0x01,0x00,            // Format Code: 1 is PCM, 3 is IEEE float
     0x01,0x00,            // Number of Channels (e.g. 2)
     0x80,0xBB,0x00,0x00,  // Samples per Second, Sample Rate (e.g. 48000)
     0x00,0xDC,0x05,0x00,  // Bytes per second, byte rate = sample rate * bits per sample * channels / 8
     0x08,0x00,            // Bytes per Sample Frame, block align = bits per sample * channels / 8
     0x20,0x00,            // bits per sample (16 for PCM, 32 for float)
     "d","a","t","a",
     0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F   // size of data section
     ]
     */
    
    let WAV_HEADER_SIZE:Int32 = 44
    let FORMAT_CODE_PCM:Int16 = 1
    
    let fileSize:Int32 = dataSize + WAV_HEADER_SIZE

    let sampleRate:Int32 = sampleRate
    let subChunkSize:Int32 = 16
    let format:Int16 = FORMAT_CODE_PCM
    let channels:Int16 = channelCount
    let bitsPerSample:Int16 = bitDepth
    let byteRate:Int32 = sampleRate * Int32(channels * bitsPerSample / 8)
    let blockAlign: Int16 = (bitsPerSample * channels) / 8
    
    let header = NSMutableData()
    
    header.append([UInt8]("RIFF".utf8), length: 4)
    
    header.append(byteArray(from: fileSize), length: 4)
    
    //WAVE
    header.append([UInt8]("WAVE".utf8), length: 4)
    
    //FMT
    header.append([UInt8]("fmt ".utf8), length: 4)
    header.append(byteArray(from: subChunkSize), length: 4)
    
    header.append(byteArray(from: format), length: 2)
    header.append(byteArray(from: channels), length: 2)
    header.append(byteArray(from: sampleRate), length: 4)
    header.append(byteArray(from: byteRate), length: 4)
    header.append(byteArray(from: blockAlign), length: 2)
    header.append(byteArray(from: bitsPerSample), length: 2)
    
    
    header.append([UInt8]("data".utf8), length: 4)
    header.append(byteArray(from: dataSize), length: 4)
    
    return header as Data
}

/**
 Creates default wav header based on default PCM constants
 
 - parameter dataSize: size of PCM data in bytes
 
 - returns : Data - wav header data
 */
public static func createDefaultWavHeader(dataSize: Int32) -> Data {
    
    return createWavHeader(sampleRate: PCM.SAMPLE_RATE_DEFAULT,
                           channelCount: Int16(PCM.CHANNEL_COUNT_DEFAULT),
                           bitDepth: Int16(PCM.BIT_DEPTH_DEFAULT),
                           pcmDataSizeInBytes: dataSize)
}

    /**
     Converts given value to byte array
     
     - parameter value:FixedWidthInteger type
     
     - returns: array of bytes
     */
    public static func byteArray<T>(from value: T) -> [UInt8] where T: FixedWidthInteger {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/56964191/4802664
        // .littleEndian is required
        return withUnsafeBytes(of: value.littleEndian) { Array($0) }
    }
    
    /**
     Generates wav audio data buffer from given header and raw PCM
     
     - parameter wavHeader: a fake RIFF WAV header (appended to PCM)
     - parameter pcmData: Linear PCM data
     
     - returns: Data
     */
    public static func generateWav(header wavHeader: Data, pcmData: Data) -> Data {
        
        var wavData = Data()
        
        wavData.append(wavHeader)
        wavData.append(pcmData)
        
        return wavData
    }
    
    /**
     Checks permission for recording and invokes callback with flag
     
     - parameter callback: clouser to invoked after checking permission
     */
    public static func checkRecordingPermission(onPermissionChecked callback: @escaping(_ isPermissionGranted: Bool) -> Void) {
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        var isPermissionGranted = false
        
        switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission {
            
        case .granted:
            isPermissionGranted = true
            break
            
        case .denied:
            isPermissionGranted = false
            break
            
        case .undetermined:
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (allowed) in
                if allowed {
                    isPermissionGranted = true
                } else {
                    isPermissionGranted = false
                }
            })
            break
            
        default:
            isPermissionGranted = false
            break
        }
        
        callback(isPermissionGranted)
    }

    /**
     Saves given audio data to specified url
     
     - parameter fileUri: file url where audio data will be saved
     */
    public static func saveAudio(to fileUri: URL, audioData: Data) {
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        Logger.logIt("save to: \(fileUri)")
        
        do {
            try audioData.write(to: fileUri)
        } catch {
            Logger.logIt(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    /**
     Encodes given PCM data into self delimited opus (`|header|data|header|data|...|`) using libopus
     
     - parameter pcmData: Linear PCM data buffer (loaded from file or coming from AudioEngine tapping)
     - parameter splitSize: size of chunk to split the given pcmData
     - returns : encoded data (encoded as: `|header|data|header|data|...|`)
     */
    public static func encodeToSelfDelimitedOpus(pcmData: Data, splitSize: Int) -> Data {
        
        Logger.logIt(#function)
        
        var encodedData = Data()
        
        var readIndex = 0
        var readStart = 0
        var readEnd = 0
        
        var pcmChunk: Data
        
        var readCount = 1
        let splitCount = (pcmData.count / splitSize)
        Logger.logIt("split count: \(splitCount)")
        
        var header: Data
        
        while readCount <=  splitCount {
            
            readStart = readIndex
            readEnd = readStart + splitSize
            
            //
            // to prevent index out of bound exception
            // check readEnd index
            //
            if(readEnd >= pcmData.count){
                readEnd = readStart + (pcmData.count - readIndex)
            }
            
            pcmChunk = pcmData[readStart..<readEnd]
            //print("chunk: \(pcmChunk)")
            
            if let encodedChunk = OpusKit.shared.encodeData(pcmChunk) {
                
                //
                // header is exactly one byte
                // header indicates size of the encoded opus data
                //
                header = Data(from: encodedChunk.count)[0..<1]
                //Logger.logIt("header: \([UInt8](header))")
                
                encodedData.append(header)
                encodedData.append(encodedChunk)
            } else {
                print("failed to encode at index: \(readStart)")
            }
            
            readIndex += splitSize
            readCount += 1
        }
        
        //
        // remaining data
        //
        //Logger.logIt("append remaining data")
        pcmChunk = pcmData[readIndex..<pcmData.count]
        
        if let encodedChunk = OpusKit.shared.encodeData(pcmChunk) {
            header = Data(from: encodedChunk.count)[0..<1]
            //Logger.logIt("header: \([UInt8](header))")
            
            encodedData.append(header)
            encodedData.append(encodedChunk)
        } else {
            print("failed to encode at index: \(readIndex)")
        }
        
        return encodedData
    }
    
    /**
     Decodes given self delimited opus data to PCM
     
     Custom opus is encoded as `|header|data|header|data|...|`
     Loops over the data, reads data size from header and takes slice/chunk of given opus data based on data size from header. Then each chunk is decode using libopus
     
     - parameter opusData: Encoded opus data buffer
     - parameter headerSizeInBytes: size of header in bytes (default is 1)
     - returns : decoded pcm data
     */
    public static  func decodeSelfDelimitedOpusToPcm(opusData: Data, headerSizeInBytes headerSize: Int = 1) -> Data {
        
        var decodedData: Data = Data()
        
        var headerData: Data
        var opusChunkSizeFromHeader = 0
        var readIndex = 0
        var readStart = 0
        var readEnd = 0
        var extractedOpusChunk: Data
        
        
        while readIndex < opusData.count {
            
            headerData = opusData[readIndex..<(readIndex + headerSize)]
            //Logger.logIt("headerData: \([UInt8](headerData))")
            
            opusChunkSizeFromHeader = Int([UInt8](headerData)[0])
            
            readStart = readIndex + headerSize
            readEnd = readStart + opusChunkSizeFromHeader
            
            extractedOpusChunk = opusData[readStart..<readEnd]
            //Logger.logIt("extracted: \(extractedOpusChunk)")
            
            if let decodedDataChunk = OpusKit.shared.decodeData(extractedOpusChunk) {
                //Logger.logIt("decodedDataChunk: \(decodedDataChunk)")
                decodedData.append(decodedDataChunk)
            } else {
                print("failed to decode at index: \(readStart)")
            }
            
            readIndex += (headerSize + opusChunkSizeFromHeader)
        }
        
        return decodedData
    }
    
    /**
     Extracts PCM only from a audio file using AVAssetReader
     
     Normally system will append some meta data while saving audio file with extension, and therefore we need to use AVAssetReader to get PCM only
     
     - parameter fileUrl : audio file url
     
     - returns: PCM  Data
     */
    public static func extractPcmOnly(from fileUrl: URL) -> Data {
        
        let pcmOnly = NSMutableData()

        do {
            
            let asset = AVAsset(url: fileUrl)
            let assetReader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
            let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first
            let outputSettings = LinearPCMRecording.LINEAR_PCM_RECODING_SETTINGS_DEFAULT
            
            let trackOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track!, outputSettings: outputSettings)
            
            assetReader.add(trackOutput)
            assetReader.startReading()
            
            Logger.logIt("reading data with AVAssetReader")
            while assetReader.status == AVAssetReader.Status.reading {
                
                if let sampleBufferRef = trackOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
                    
                    if let blockBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBufferRef) {
                        
                        let bufferLength = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBufferRef)
                        let data = NSMutableData(length: bufferLength)
                        
                        // func CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(_ theSourceBuffer: CMBlockBuffer, atOffset offsetToData: Int, dataLength: Int, destination: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> OSStatus
                        CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(blockBufferRef, atOffset: 0, dataLength: bufferLength, destination: data!.mutableBytes)
                        
                        let samples = data!.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt16.self)
                        pcmOnly.append(samples, length: bufferLength)
                        CMSampleBufferInvalidate(sampleBufferRef)
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    Logger.logIt("failed to copy next")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Logger.logIt(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        return pcmOnly as Data
    }
}
```

## Additional classes

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import OpusKit


public class Audio {
    public static let SAMPLE_RATE_16_KHZ: opus_int32 = 16_000
    public static let SAMPLE_RATE_8_KHZ: opus_int32 = 8_000
    public static let SAMPLE_RATE_DEFAULT = SAMPLE_RATE_16_KHZ
    public static let MONO:Int32 = 1
    public static let CHANNEL_COUNT_DEFAULT:Int32 = MONO
    public static let BIT_DEPTH_DEFAULT:Int32 = 16
    public static let FRAME_DURATION_DEFAULT = 20 // milliseconds
    // FRAME_SIZE = FRAME (duration in millisecond) * SAMPLE_RATE
    public static let FRAME_SIZE_DEFAULT:Int32 = (SAMPLE_RATE_DEFAULT / 1000) *  Int32(FRAME_DURATION_DEFAULT)
}

public class PCM: Audio {
    public static let SPLIT_CHUNK_SIZE_DEFAULT:Int = Int(FRAME_SIZE_DEFAULT * (BIT_DEPTH_DEFAULT / 8))
}

public class WAV: Audio {
    public static let HEADER_SIZE:Int32 = 44  // always 44 bytes
    public static let WAV_HEADER_FORMAT_PCM:Int16 = 1
    public static let WAV_HEADER_SUB_CHUNK_SIZE:Int32 = 16 // always 16
}

public class Opus: Audio {
    public static let ENCODED_OUTPUT_MEMORY_SIZE_LIMIT:Int32 = 255 // Size of the allocated memory for the output payload
    public static let OPUS_ENCODER_BUFFER_SIZE:Int32 = 1275 // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707654/4802664
}

public class PCMRecordingSetting {

    private static let SAMPLE_RATE_16_KHZ = 16_000
    private static let BIT_DEPTH_16 = 16
    private static let CHANNEL_MONO = 1
 
    public var sampleRate:Int = SAMPLE_RATE_16_KHZ {
        willSet {
            updateBitRate()
            updateLinearPCMRecordingSettings()
        }
    }

    public var channelCount:Int = CHANNEL_MONO {
        willSet {
            updateBitRate()
            updateLinearPCMRecordingSettings()
        }
    }

    public var bitDepth:Int = BIT_DEPTH_16 {
        willSet {
            updateBitRate()
            updateLinearPCMRecordingSettings()
        }
    }

    public private(set) var bitRate = SAMPLE_RATE_16_KHZ * BIT_DEPTH_16 * CHANNEL_MONO
    private func updateBitRate(){
        bitRate = sampleRate * bitDepth * channelCount
    }

    public static let LINEAR_PCM_DEFAULT = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
        AVSampleRateKey: SAMPLE_RATE_16_KHZ,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: CHANNEL_MONO,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: BIT_DEPTH_16,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false
        ] as [String : Any]
    
    public var recordingSettings = LINEAR_PCM_DEFAULT
    
    private func updateLinearPCMRecordingSettings(){
        
        Logger.debug(#function)
        
        recordingSettings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
            AVSampleRateKey: sampleRate,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: channelCount,
            AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: bitDepth,
            AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false
            ] as [String : Any]
    }

    public init(sampleRate: Int, channelCount: Int, bitDepth: Int){
        self.sampleRate = sampleRate
        self.channelCount = channelCount
        self.bitDepth = bitDepth
        updateBitRate()
        updateLinearPCMRecordingSettings()
    }

    public static let `default` = PCMRecordingSetting(sampleRate: SAMPLE_RATE_16_KHZ, channelCount: CHANNEL_MONO, bitDepth: BIT_DEPTH_16)
}
```

Comment: About decoding self-delimited opus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597315/playing-custom-opus-audio-file-in-ios

Comment: Hassan what is `Opus` in your code? `Use of unresolved identifier 'Opus'`

Comment: @user2875404 `Opus` is a class with some constants. I updated the answer, check 'Additional classes' at bottom.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it!

Comment: Last thing missing for me is the PCM class. If you could add that too I would be very grateful

Comment: Oh and `LinearPCMRecording`

Comment: @user2875404 I was trying to keep the answer short. Check now =>  I added all additional classes.

Comment: @HassanTareq thank you so much. Last bit is missing - what's in the  `LinearPCMRecording.LINEAR_PCM_RECODING_SETTINGS_DEFAULT`?

Comment: @user2161301 I skipped that because answer can not have more than 3K chars. I created a gist for you (LinearPCMRecording class) => https://gist.github.com/hovermind/d114548c073573f08e98541f7f9b6b5b

Comment: How do you set bitrate in opuskit ? i can not user opus_encoder_ctl !!

Comment: @Ahmed bit rate will be automatically calculated from sampleRate, bitDepth and channelCount => https://gist.github.com/hovermind/d114548c073573f08e98541f7f9b6b5b

Comment: yes this is true, but what i want to do is set the value of bitrate, like what i did in java JNI code, where i use this function to set it opus_encoder_ctl(enc, OPUS_SET_BITRATE(BITRATE)); but in opusKit i can not call this function , is there a documentation for opusKit ?

Comment: @Ahmed from my understanding, opusKit does not have such function (in my opinion, you don't need to set bit-rate). If you really want to set bit-rate, check source code of opusKit and call "native c" code directly from Swift.

Comment: Hello Hassan,
Im getting "OpusKit - Something went wrong while decoding data: Invalid/unsupported request number." error while trying to decode .opus and .ogg files. Am I on the wrong way ?

Comment: @TuracBey please check here: <https://hovermind.com/ios/libopus-kit> and see what went wrong